# Can't access KubeAPI port in kubernetes + rancher

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubectl, rancher, rke

I have the following configuration to up the rke. when I up the `rke`. I get the error.

rancher-cluster.yml

```
nodes:
  - address: 192.168.88.246
    internal_address: 172.17.0.1
    user: dockeruser
    role: [controlplane,worker,etcd]
  - address: 192.168.88.243
    internal_address: 172.17.0.1
    user: dockeruser
    role: [controlplane,worker,etcd]
  - address: 192.168.88.245
    internal_address: 172.17.0.1
    user: dockeruser
    role: [controlplane,worker,etcd]

services:
  etcd:
    snapshot: true
    creation: 6h
    retention: 24h
```

when I up the `rke`, i get the following error

```
FATA[0059] [network] Can't access KubeAPI port [6443] on Control Plane host: 192.168.88.245
```

detials log

```
[root@localhost ~]# rke up --config ./rancher-cluster.yml
INFO[0000] Building Kubernetes cluster
INFO[0000] [dialer] Setup tunnel for host [192.168.88.243]
INFO[0000] [dialer] Setup tunnel for host [192.168.88.245]
INFO[0000] [dialer] Setup tunnel for host [192.168.88.246]
INFO[0001] [state] Found local kube config file, trying to get state from cluster
INFO[0001] [reconcile] Local config is not valid, rebuilding admin config
INFO[0001] [reconcile] Rebuilding and updating local kube config
INFO[0001] Successfully Deployed local admin kubeconfig at [./kube_config_rancher-cluster.yml]
INFO[0014] Successfully Deployed local admin kubeconfig at [./kube_config_rancher-cluster.yml]
INFO[0026] Successfully Deployed local admin kubeconfig at [./kube_config_rancher-cluster.yml]
INFO[0026] [state] Fetching cluster state from Kubernetes
INFO[0056] Timed out waiting for kubernetes cluster to get state
INFO[0056] [state] Fetching cluster state from Nodes
INFO[0057] [network] Deploying port listener containers
INFO[0058] [network] Successfully started [rke-etcd-port-listener] container on host [192.168.88.246]
INFO[0058] [network] Successfully started [rke-etcd-port-listener] container on host [192.168.88.243]
INFO[0058] [network] Successfully started [rke-etcd-port-listener] container on host [192.168.88.245]
INFO[0059] [network] Successfully started [rke-worker-port-listener] container on host [192.168.88.243]
INFO[0059] [network] Successfully started [rke-worker-port-listener] container on host [192.168.88.246]
INFO[0059] [network] Successfully started [rke-worker-port-listener] container on host [192.168.88.245]
INFO[0059] [network] Port listener containers deployed successfully
INFO[0059] [network] Running etcd <-> etcd port checks
INFO[0060] [network] Successfully started [rke-port-checker] container on host [192.168.88.246]
INFO[0060] [network] Successfully started [rke-port-checker] container on host [192.168.88.243]
INFO[0060] [network] Successfully started [rke-port-checker] container on host [192.168.88.245]
INFO[0060] [network] Running control plane -> etcd port checks
INFO[0061] [network] Successfully started [rke-port-checker] container on host [192.168.88.246]
INFO[0061] [network] Successfully started [rke-port-checker] container on host [192.168.88.243]
INFO[0061] [network] Successfully started [rke-port-checker] container on host [192.168.88.245]
INFO[0061] [network] Running control plane -> worker port checks
INFO[0061] [network] Successfully started [rke-port-checker] container on host [192.168.88.246]
INFO[0061] [network] Successfully started [rke-port-checker] container on host [192.168.88.245]
INFO[0061] [network] Successfully started [rke-port-checker] container on host [192.168.88.243]
INFO[0061] [network] Running workers -> control plane port checks
INFO[0062] [network] Successfully started [rke-port-checker] container on host [192.168.88.245]
INFO[0062] [network] Successfully started [rke-port-checker] container on host [192.168.88.243]
INFO[0062] [network] Successfully started [rke-port-checker] container on host [192.168.88.246]
INFO[0062] [network] Checking KubeAPI port Control Plane hosts
FATA[0062] [network] Can't access KubeAPI port [6443] on Control Plane host: 192.168.88.245
[root@localhost ~]# rke up --config ./rancher-cluster.yml
INFO[0000] Building Kubernetes cluster
INFO[0000] [dialer] Setup tunnel for host [192.168.88.246]
INFO[0000] [dialer] Setup tunnel for host [192.168.88.243]
INFO[0001] [dialer] Setup tunnel for host [192.168.88.245]
INFO[0001] [state] Found local kube config file, trying to get state from cluster
INFO[0001] [reconcile] Local config is not valid, rebuilding admin config
INFO[0001] [reconcile] Rebuilding and updating local kube config
INFO[0001] Successfully Deployed local admin kubeconfig at [./kube_config_rancher-cluster.yml]
INFO[0011] Successfully Deployed local admin kubeconfig at [./kube_config_rancher-cluster.yml]
INFO[0023] Successfully Deployed local admin kubeconfig at [./kube_config_rancher-cluster.yml]
INFO[0023] [state] Fetching cluster state from Kubernetes
INFO[0053] Timed out waiting for kubernetes cluster to get state
INFO[0053] [state] Fetching cluster state from Nodes
INFO[0054] [network] Deploying port listener containers
INFO[0055] [network] Successfully started [rke-etcd-port-listener] container on host [192.168.88.245]
INFO[0055] [network] Successfully started [rke-cp-port-listener] container on host [192.168.88.243]
INFO[0056] [network] Successfully started [rke-worker-port-listener] container on host [192.168.88.245]
INFO[0056] [network] Port listener containers deployed successfully
INFO[0056] [network] Running etcd <-> etcd port checks
INFO[0056] [network] Successfully started [rke-port-checker] container on host [192.168.88.243]
INFO[0056] [network] Successfully started [rke-port-checker] container on host [192.168.88.246]
INFO[0056] [network] Successfully started [rke-port-checker] container on host [192.168.88.245]
INFO[0057] [network] Running control plane -> etcd port checks
INFO[0057] [network] Successfully started [rke-port-checker] container on host [192.168.88.246]
INFO[0057] [network] Successfully started [rke-port-checker] container on host [192.168.88.245]
INFO[0057] [network] Successfully started [rke-port-checker] container on host [192.168.88.243]
INFO[0057] [network] Running control plane -> worker port checks
INFO[0058] [network] Successfully started [rke-port-checker] container on host [192.168.88.245]
INFO[0058] [network] Successfully started [rke-port-checker] container on host [192.168.88.246]
INFO[0058] [network] Successfully started [rke-port-checker] container on host [192.168.88.243]
INFO[0058] [network] Running workers -> control plane port checks
INFO[0058] [network] Successfully started [rke-port-checker] container on host [192.168.88.246]
INFO[0058] [network] Successfully started [rke-port-checker] container on host [192.168.88.245]
INFO[0059] [network] Successfully started [rke-port-checker] container on host [192.168.88.243]
INFO[0059] [network] Checking KubeAPI port Control Plane hosts
FATA[0059] [network] Can't access KubeAPI port [6443] on Control Plane host: 192.168.88.245
```

In 192.168.88.24 (node), `kube-apiserver` is already running.

[image]

I already open the port

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=6443/tcp --permanent
firewall-cmd --reload
```

Comment: Can you share your cluster config?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? I'm running into the same issue on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: @StefanLasiewski, I remove internal address. It is OK. Currently, I don't need to use it.

Comment: I would say rancher is trying to connect the container from outside, and the port is not exposed. If you expect the port to be accessible without explicitly pass `-p`,the request must be done from another container. Is that the case?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the internal_address IPs are all the same. This setting used to set what IP address the nodes should communicate on for node-to-node connections.
We mostly see this option when your servers are behind a NAT.

Please try the following cluster.yml

```
nodes:
  - address: 192.168.88.246
    internal_address: 192.168.88.246
    user: dockeruser
    role: [controlplane,worker,etcd]
  - address: 192.168.88.243
    internal_address: 192.168.88.243
    user: dockeruser
    role: [controlplane,worker,etcd]
  - address: 192.168.88.245
    internal_address: 192.168.88.245
    user: dockeruser
    role: [controlplane,worker,etcd]

services:
  etcd:
    snapshot: true
    creation: 6h
    retention: 24h
```