# FATA[0168] [network] Can't access KubeAPI port [6443] on Control Plane host

Tags: docker, kubernetes, port, rancher, rancher-rke

I am trying to setup an RKE cluster with a config file. I have 4 virtual machines docker, docker.io are installed. Ufw is disabled, have done everything as [here](https://github.com/justmeandopensource/kubernetes/tree/master/rancher/rke)  .

I connect via SSH,
can connect succesfully with root and home user which I added to docker group.

I clean all the machines, stopping dockers, remove volumes and images and remove files created under /etc, /var etc. I keep getting same error. As I said above, ufw is disabled and inactive and netstat gives me this when installing.

In `docker ps` I get

> c8c00552f6bb   rancher/rke-tools:v0.1.78   "/docker-entrypoint.…"
> About a minute ago   Up About a minute   80/tcp,
> 0.0.0.0:6443->1337/tcp                           rke-cp-port-listener

Netstat:

> tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6443            0.0.0.0:*
> LISTEN      7171/docker-proxy

I did [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54513414/cant-access-kubeapi-port-in-kubernetes-rancher) and nothing changed. I clean machines everytime I try another solution and it costs time. Any help is great now. Thanks.

Comment: Did you resolve the issue? Pls post RKE config file and logs if still need inputs.